# Where do I keep the download button on a website?

Tags: website-design, buttons, download

I have developed a promotional website for an iOS application. The introductory view of the page contains - aside from a short description and screenshots - an official AppStore badge, which will link to my application's iTunes page. Now, what if the user is not quite sure, if he/she wants to download this app and scrolls down to get to know more about it ? Where would be (a) good place(s) to put a download button ?

Previous iterations of this very page had a fixed badge at the top-left corner of the page, which basically led the users to my iTunes product page. Is this encouraging and recommended ? Or will it just end up being a nuisance to the user ?

Should I maybe introduce the download button every x pixels, or just at the end of the page ?

I would love to hear your opinions!

Comment: Put a small button on every page (like "Ask Question" on UX) and a big download button on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate banner notifications, but that's a personal preference. Now in regards to sticky buttons, I think that's a little less obstrusive, but there definitely are ways of making the experience sleeker and much more beautiful.

For example, you could have a download button in the screen when page loads, and as soon as the user scrolls, anmiated it and shrink it into the navigation bar, once the user scrolls all the way to the bottom, you can reanimate it back into the center.

I've made a little quick animation to show you what I mean:

[Download Button Idea http://s7.postimg.org/6rbx52ieh/Download_Idea.gif](http://s7.postimg.org/6rbx52ieh/Download_Idea.gif)

In case you can't see it, [click here](http://s7.postimg.org/6rbx52ieh/Download_Idea.gif).

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: I can't agree more with you on the banners and I like your proposal. I will definitely try that!

Comment: What's the software you used for this animation ?

Comment: @edi9999 Adobe After Effects!

Answer (score 2):

On iOS App promotional pages, it's not uncommon to link to the app download page in App Store at the top of the page, above the actual content. To the best of my knowledge this is becoming (if not already) the convention to link to app downloads while browsing web pages on iOS devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would agree with Chipperyman. If the page is to promote the app, the main action should be the most prominent on the page, namely a 'Download' button or link.

On subsequent pages, you can keep the link at a fixed location on the page to maintain consistency.